# The order of my jquery validator is working wrong, and I have no idea why

Tags: javascript, jquery

My form validator works, but it works in a certain order, if I check the checkbox, it works fine, but if I fill the inputs first and then use the checkbox, it not works, unless I type something in the inputs

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#send').attr('disabled', true);
  $('.input,#check').on('keyup', function() {

    var text_value = $('.input-cpk').val();
    if (text_value !== '' && (document.getElementById('check').checked)) {
      $('#send').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#send').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="block oh fr col-9 margem-d2 text-left" action="enviar-calculo.php" method="post" target="votar" name="cpk">

  <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="input-cpk col-20">
  <input type="number" name="telefone" class="input-cpk-tel">
  <input type="submit" value="CALCULAR" id="send" class="f-josefin-s-b f-branca bg-amarelo botao" onclick="output();">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="others" />

</form>
```

Comment: You only perform validation during `keyup`, and that only happens in the input fields, not the checkbox.

Comment: The event for a checkbox is `click`, not `keyup`.

Comment: I doubt the checkbox has a keyup that is invoked by clicking, so I imagine it's disabling initially because the checkbox isn't checked, then keeping it disabled until you type again.

Comment: Change the event from `keyup` to `input`!

Comment: Note that `$('.input` won't match anything.

Comment: As @Barmar said, you need to listen to two different events and then you can call a common function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only run your validation code during the `keyup` event, which only happens on the input boxes. You also need to do validation during a `click` event on the checkbox.

You can put multiple event names in the argument to `.on()`, to handle both with the same code.

You also have an incorrect class `.input`, there are no elements with `class="input"` in the HTML. I've changed it to `.input-cpk`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#send').prop('disabled', true);
  $('.input-cpk,#check').on('keyup click', function() {

    var text_value = $('.input-cpk').val();
    if (text_value !== '' && (document.getElementById('check').checked)) {
      $('#send').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#send').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="block oh fr col-9 margem-d2 text-left" action="enviar-calculo.php" method="post" target="votar" name="cpk">

  <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="input-cpk col-20">
  <input type="number" name="telefone" class="input-cpk-tel">
  <input type="submit" value="CALCULAR" id="send" class="f-josefin-s-b f-branca bg-amarelo botao" onclick="output();">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="others" />

</form>
```

Comment: Still not working if you empty the inputs the button is still enabled!

Comment: That's fixed now.

Comment: Should probably be using `prop()` for Boolean properties like `disabled`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Changed it, although jQuery automatically fixes up calls like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using the wrong selector.

Try this
$('input,#check').on('keyup', function() {

Instead of this
$('.input,#check').on('keyup', function() {

Additionally you might want to use the .on('change') instead of .on('keyup')